# Read JSON object from POST in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to bind POST data to object as below:

```
[Route("ta_iba/test")]
[HttpPost]
public string test(Photo p)
{
     ............
}

public class Photo
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}
WebApiConfig:     
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I'm using fiddler to test:

```
Header:
User-Agent: Fiddler
ContentType: application/json
Host: localhost:50653
Content-Length: 50
Body:
{"url":"xxxx","caption":"yyy","width":50,"height":50}
```

But i'm getting error as `HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type`. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the request parameter as `Content-Type`, not `ContentType`:

```
Header:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:50653
Content-Length: 50
Body:
{"url":"xxxx","caption":"yyy","width":50,"height":50}
```